# Setting for open application(consist of Node.js and Redis) to the public

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis, socket.io

There are some problems about Scrumblr(GPL Web Application).
Scrumblr consist of Node.js and Redis.
This is Github url : https://github.com/aliasaria/scrumblr .

I  run "scrumblr" at localhost:8080 on Ubuntu 11.10.
I configured global IP address on my Ubuntu.
However, I can't access Scrumblr when I accessed "http://global IP address:8080/".
(Error message: Can't establish a connection to the server )

How should I modify scrumblr's  source code?
So, please tell me place(directory, file)where I should modify to access Scrumblr via "http://global IP address:8080/".

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is open up the port 8080 in my firewall so I CAN access it externally, then server the app with localhost:8080 -- sometimes you may have to bind that to an ip, but I'm not sure. I use express which basically takes care of that for me.

Then I edit my /etc/hosts file and map foo.myapp to my public ip address...then I can browse to http://foo.myapp:8080 from anywhere.

Comment: I appreciate your kindness.I could access Scrumblr via "http://global IP address:8080/",just now. I mistook code about setting for IP address;) Many thanks for your advice.